# Notepad ++ generate lines with the same string

Tags: notepad++

Using notepad ++, how to create lines from an empty file?

I want to create/generate 999 lines with the same string.

Comment: Type one line, Ctrl-C the entire line, Ctrl-V 998 times. Or you can automate it with some coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the macro function, record the pasting of 1 line, start the macro and repeat 998 time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running on windows and the blank file already exists, you can do

1. Open the file in Notepad++
2. Go to Run > Run... or press F5
3. Enter `cmd.exe /C "FOR /L %i IN (1,1,999) DO echo Your text goes here >> "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""`
4. Reload the file when prompted

These should fill your file with the same string.